# Saving state of angular app between page reloads

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

What would be a good approach to implement state persistence between page reloads? Right now I am not talking about state in context of ngrx. I am referring to that case when you refresh the page and everything seems to be gone : user is logged out, all changes that are not saved on backend are gone and so on.

At first I thought that this can be somehow implemented using localStorage and then init everything in ngOnInit() in every component I need, but it sounds like inventing a wheel. I believe there should be a ready solution, or some pattern.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search in the web points to [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage) which helps to store  application state in localstorage. A sample implementation from their website below.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducerMap, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';
import { reducers } from './reducers';
 
 
const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IState> = {todos, visibilityFilter};
 
export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({keys: ['todos']})(reducer);
}
const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(
        reducers,
        {metaReducers}
    )
  ]
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the stuff you need in localstorage, an write actions (because you mentioned ngrx) that access the localstorage, store it in the state and all the components just access that data though selector or any other preferred way. Hope that helps